# Using setInterval to replace text from api

Tags: javascript, setinterval

When the button is clicked I would like my text to change every 3 secs. I am using setInterval I can see the numbers changing in console.log but the text isn't changing and i don't know why.

What I've tried:

```
setInterval(function() {
                   var quote = jokesArray[jokeNum];
         console.log(jokeTxt.innerHTML = quote);
} 

setInterval(function() {
               if (jokeTxt.innerHTML !== "") {
                   jokeTxt.innerHTML = "";
                   jokeNum++;
                   jokeTxt.innerHTML = jokesArray[jokeNum];
          }


setInterval(function() {
               var quote = jokesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() % 586) + 1];
     console.log(jokeTxt.innerHTML = quote);
```

Full Script:

```
function main() {
        var myApi = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random";

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var jokesArray = [];
        var randomIndex = Math.random();
        var randomizer = (randomIndex % 586) + 1;
        var jokeNum = Math.floor(randomizer);
        var jokeTxt = document.getElementById("jokeTxt");

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                var jokesJSON = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                var jokes = jokesJSON.value.joke;
                for (var i = 0; i < jokes.length; i++) {
                    jokesArray.push(jokes);
                }
                //allJokes = jokesArray[jokeNum];

                setInterval(function() {
               var quote = jokesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() % 586) + 1];
     console.log(jokeTxt.innerHTML = quote); 

                },3000);
            }
        }

        xhttp.open("GET", myApi, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    var myBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
    myBtn.onclick = main;
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns `float` on `[0..1)`. Try `Math.random() * 1000 % jokes.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API you're using only returns a single joke at a time, rather than an array of multiple jokes. In your code, you're treating `var jokes` as though it's an array of many jokes, but this is actually just a string - i.e., one joke. Iterating over this variable means you're looping over the string and performing an action for each character in the joke.

The API also returns a random joke from their database, so instead of building a local array and selecting a random element, you could just send multiple requests to the API and get a new (random) joke each time. Here's a modification of your code that does this:

```js
var jokeTxt = document.getElementById("jokeTxt");

function getJoke() {
  var myApi = "https://api.icndb.com/jokes/random";
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var jokesJSON = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
      var joke = jokesJSON.value.joke;
      jokeTxt.innerHTML = joke;
    }
  }

  xhttp.open("GET", myApi, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function startJokes() {
  // get the first joke right away...
  getJoke();
  // ...then get a new joke every 3 seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    getJoke();
  }, 3000);
}

var myBtn = document.getElementById("btn");
myBtn.onclick = startJokes;
```

```html
<button id="btn">Start the Jokes!</button>
<div id="jokeTxt"><div>
```